# How to run GitHub workflow on every commit of a push

Tags: github-actions

I have some tests that I would like to run on every commit of my repository. I have the following script in my repo:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo "my tests"
```

Unfortunately, if I push some new commits to my repository, the tests are only run against the latest commit. Is there a way to test all commits?

Comment: I assume that above workflow is not exatly as your, right? What do you mean by `the tests are only run agains the latest commit`?

Comment: No, the `run:` section is more involved, this is just the placeholder. What I mean with `the tests are only run agains the latest commit`, is that if I push a number of new commits to my repo, only the last commit of that push is tested. I would like to test all those commits.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to to this by checking out individual commits and building each one in a single `run:` step.

In order to do this, the `fetch-depth` option for the `checkout` action needs to be `0` to checkout the full git tree.

I did something like this using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to iterate and checkout each commit.

Using just the `git` command line tool, the [rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) command could be used to create a list of commits.

The tricky part is figuring out the commit range. For pull requests, GitHub actions provides `github.head_ref` and `github.base_ref` properties ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)) that could be used to create the commit range. However, these properties are not available for other events, like `push` (in that case, `github.ref` could be used with a fixed branch name like `origin/main`).

Here is a simple example. It may need more a advanced query for `rev-list` to handle cases where `base_ref` is not an ancestor of `head_ref`, but I will leave that for other SO questions to answer.

```yaml
name: CI

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: |
          for commit in $(git rev-list ${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.head_ref }}); do
              git checkout $commit
              echo "run test"
          done
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on [David Lechner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976323/david-lechner)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708371/how-to-run-github-workflow-on-every-commit-of-a-push/64839656#64839656):

```
name: CI

on: 
  push:
    # only trigger on branches, not on tags
    branches: '**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # checkout full tree
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: |
          for commit in $(git rev-list ${{ github.event.before}}..${{ github.sha}}); do
              git checkout $commit
              echo "run test"
          done
```

As per [the docs on the `github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) and [the docs on the `push` webhook event data](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push) `{{github.event.before}}` is replaced by the commit sha before the push. `{{github.sha}}` or `{{github.event.after}}` is replaced by the sha of the latest commit that was pushed:

**Push event payload (for a pushed tag; [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#push))**

```json
{
  "ref": "refs/tags/simple-tag",
  "before": "6113728f27ae82c7b1a177c8d03f9e96e0adf246",
  "after": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "created": false,
  "deleted": true,
  "forced": false,
  "base_ref": null,
  "compare": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World/compare/6113728f27ae...000000000000",
  "commits": [],
  "head_commit": null,
 [...]
}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround but it doesn't appear to publish a commit status for each of the commits on the branch.

Comment: @Hannes for this you'll have to create checkruns manually or via some action. See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-checks-api.

Comment: on non-fast-forward pushes it may give error diagnostic `fatal: Invalid revision range ...` as there is no `github.event.before .. github.sha`. IIRC it needs the common ancestor then.