# Github actions does not run the test for all commits

Tags: git, github-actions

I need to test all `commits` that come with a given `push` or `pull request` and not just the last `commit`.

I analyzed some questions and answers here in the community and found the following: [[Click Here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708371/how-to-run-github-workflow-on-every-commit-of-a-push)

However, I checked the `pipeline` and I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]

And he's not pushing all the `commits`, just the last one yet.

My `.yaml`:

```
# prettier-ignore
name: CONTINUOUS INTEGRATION

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, develop ]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
    - name: Check out Git repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - run: |
        for commit in $(git rev-list ${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.head_ref }}); do
            git checkout $commit
            echo "run test"
        done
    - name: Use Nodejs ${{ matrix.node-version }} - ${{ matrix.architecture }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    - name: Yarn [Install]
      uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
      with:
        cmd: install
    - name: Yarn [Lint]
      uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
      with:
        cmd: lint-check
    - name: Yarn [Test]
      uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
      with:
        cmd: test

  deploy:
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
    - name: Check out Git repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - run: |
        for commit in $(git rev-list ${{ github.base_ref }}..${{ github.head_ref }}); do
            git checkout $commit
            echo "run test"
        done
    - name: Vercel Deploy
      uses: amondnet/vercel-action@v20
      with:
        vercel-token: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        vercel-args: '--prod'
        vercel-org-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID}}
        vercel-project-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID}}
      env:
       REACT_APP_AUTHOR: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_AUTHOR }}
       REACT_APP_DESCRIPTION: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_DESCRIPTION }}
       REACT_APP_KEYWORDS: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_KEYWORDS }}
       REACT_APP_TITLE: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_TITLE }}
```

**What is this?
How to solve?**

Comment: Here are some topics that might interest you: https://github.community/t/how-to-run-github-workflow-on-every-commit-of-a-push/142030/8 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155541/is-it-possible-in-git-to-push-commits-one-by-one-instead-of-all-of-them-at-once 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+test+every+commit

Comment: I had already read these links, so much so that I already commented on the question. I do not know why my question is being closed, since I have already used what was given as answers in other questions and posted in mine. The question is, does it only work in pull_request when you have multiple commits on a branch? And when you have a push, would you have to push each commit, is that it?

Comment: If you would have read the answer you copied the code from, you would know that you have to adapt it for pushes.
Also, having your question closed two days ago and then deleting it and recreating it to circumvent the closure is not the way to go. Rather edit it to disambiguate it from the duplicate / say why the duplicate doesn't work for you.

Comment: @riQQ 
But this is the answer I want, what would this "push adaptation" look like? even if I knew myself and had found the answer, I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: Then you should have specified that more clearly in your question. I don't know the answer. Either you have to wait for someone or look into it yourself (find out if there is a way to get the last ref before the push).

Comment: It seems like your first question is: *How, in a GitHub action, do I obtain the hash IDs of new commits introduced into the repository? For instance, if someone ran `git push origin hash:newbranch` or `git push origin develop` from their laptop to GitHub, this might introduce one, two, or a dozen commits. The old and new hash IDs are available to a post-receive hook; what is available to a GitHub action?* This is a GitHub-specific question, not a Git question.

Comment: Once you know the answer to this question, you either have, or can construct, the appropriate arguments to `git rev-list`. If you need to construct them, you may also need one more answer first, namely: *In a GitHub action, if I have the new hash ID, is the action run before, or after, updating branch names?* That will tell you whether `--all --not <rev>` or `--branches --not <rev>` work.